# Alternate text color inside a html tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

For some reason the editor is very limited and I can't color my text

What I want to achieve on text inside a HTML tag:
`Black White Black White`

How the HTML look:

```
<h3 class="widget-title">Black White Black White</h3>
```

I know it is possible to fix this by adding span tags:

```
<h3 class="widget-title">Black <span style="color:FFF;">White</span> Black <span style="color:FFF;">White</span></h3>
```

Are there any easier work-around on this? Is this supported in CSS3 somehow or do I have to code this in JQuery to achieve it?

---

Thanks for the answer guys. Perhaps, I wasn't clear on my question... What I want was make the even word to change color. Here is a modified snippet from undefined.

```
var txt = $('.widget-title').text().split(' ');
var str = "";
$.each(txt, function(i,v){
    if ( (i&1) == 1 ) {
        str += " <span style='color:red'>" + v + "</span> ";
    } else {
        str += " " + v;
    }
})

$('.widget-title').html(str)
```

Comment: To set a color directly to TEXT_NODE is impossible. Afaik using spanned elements is the only way how to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var txt = $('.widget-title').text().split(' ');
var str = "";
$.each(txt, function(i,v){
  if (v == 'something') {
    str += "<span class='something'>" + v + "</span>"
  } else { str += " " + v}
})

$('.widget-title').html(str)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/72552/)

Comment: undefined to clarify I won't be targeting the 'White' word only. The text could be 'Lorem Ipsum Doler' or 'Dog Cat Bird'.  Which 'Ipsum' and 'Cat' would colored be white. I am not at home, so I can't test it yet.

Comment: @edden you can replace the `target` with every word that should be colored, I've added a demo.

Comment: @edden If you want every odd word to be white, you can use `if ( (i&1) == 1 ) str += " <span style='color:#fff'>" + v + "</span> ";`

Comment: @Thomas as a matter of fact I want the even words to change color. Thanks for the follow-up!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be exactly what you're looking for:

http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=6858

(found with "the Google")

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by javascript:

```
var title = document.getElementsByClassName('widget-title')[0],
    titleText = title.innerHTML,
    words = titleText.split(' '),
    len = words.length,
    i;

title.innerHTML = '';

for (i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
    var elem = document.createElement('span');
    elem.innerHTML = words[i];
    elem.style.color = words[i];
    title.appendChild(elem);
}
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/kastU/2/

Answer (score -1):

Following is the code to do this with PHP,  You need to call function `colorize("Enter text which you want to see in Black and White style");`

```
<?php 
function colorize($text) {
$array = explode(' ', $text);
$index = 1;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($index%2) {

        echo '<span style="color:#FFF;">';
        echo $value;
        echo '</span>';
    } else {

        echo '<span style="color:#000;">';
        echo $value;
        echo '</span>';
    }
    $index++;
}
}


?>
```